# Animate an element to an unknown location in the document

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I have something like a message div that will contain some info of sorts.

I need to animate this text to somewhere else on the DOM, the thing is, I don't know where exactly (in offsets) the text starts from or needs to be animated to.

**[Take a look at this](http://jsfiddle.net/KhVuS/1/)** and you'll see what I mean, The order of the divs won't necessarily be in this order

Also the size of the log div will get bigger as more messages come and I need it to animate to the exact spot that the text will end up.

Comment: I took a look, I don't see at all what you mean.

Comment: I dont understand where you are trying to move the $log div to (in relation to the other elements on the page)

Comment: @Chris: Updated, now can you tell, I'm "moving" text from one div to another, I just want to make it happen with an animation

Comment: In your structure, where would you like it to animate to? After the old comment? Right above it?

Comment: @citizenconn: After, it's being appended, not prepended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if that's what you're after:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dx=$('#message').offset().left;
    var dy=$('#message').offset().top;
    var ox=$('#log').offset().left;
    var oy=$('#log').offset().top;
    $("#log")
        .css({"position": "absolute","left":ox+"px", "top":oy+"px"})
        .animate({"top":dy+"px","left":dx+"px"}, 500, function() {
            $('#message').text($(this).text());
        });
});
```

fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/KhVuS/9/

Comment: Awesome but [changing the message div location](http://jsfiddle.net/KhVuS/10/) doesn't work

Comment: That's because I mixed up dy and dx in the animate function. I have fixed it now in the code above. New fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/KhVuS/12/